# Python Linklist with many data

Tags: python

I need to implement a linklist to search and add students to an existing group of students. The data students include student ID and name. eg

```
studentList = [
student = ("11", "John"),
student = ("12", "Cindy"),
student = ("13", "Tracy"),
]
```

I have the following code so far but it can only be used for a single data, how to include more than one data? How to successfully search for a student?

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__ (self, code, name, n = None):
        self.data = code
        self.data = name
        self.next_node = n

    def get_next (self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_next (self, n):
        self.next_node = n

    def get_data (self):
        return self.data

    def set_data (self, d):
        self.data = d


class LinkedList (object):

    def __init__(self, r = None):
        self.root = r
        self.size = 0

    def get_size (self):
        return self.size

    def add (self, d):
        new_node = Node (d, self.root)
        self.root = new_node
        self.size += 1

    def find (self, d):
         this_node = self.root
         while this_node:
             if this_node.get_data() == d:
             return d
         else:
            this_node = this_node.get_next()
         return None

myList = LinkedList()
myList.add(5, "Trevor")
myList.add(10, "Trevor")
print("size="+str(myList.get_size()))
print(myList.find(10))
```

Comment: I submit that you do not, in fact, "need to implement a linklist" to do this. Just use a `list`.

Comment: I also suggest using a `namedtuple` for your `node` object: `from collections import namedtuple as nt`, `node = nt('node', 'code name')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in list. list.append to add to the list and use list comprehension or filters to find in list. see the link https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

Below are my modifications. You were missing the string parameter. Also, you had two data variables in your initial code.

```
class Node(object):

def __init__ (self, code, name, n = None): #here you have code and name
    self.data1 = code #you need to change this to data 1
    self.data2 = name #you need to change this to data 2 --> they can't have the same name
    self.next_node = n

def get_next (self):
    return self.next_node

def set_next (self, n):
    self.next_node = n

def get_data (self):
    return self.data1    # update this to data1 to reflect the code

def set_data (self, d):
    self.data1 = d

class LinkedList (object):

def __init__(self, r = None):
    self.root = r
    self.size = 0

def get_size (self):
    return self.size

def add (self, d, s):    # have this accept d and s (string)
    new_node = Node (d, s, self.root)    #include a string parameter
    self.root = new_node
    self.size += 1

def find (self, d):
     this_node = self.root
     while this_node:
         if this_node.get_data() == d:
             return d
     else:
        this_node = this_node.get_next()
     return None
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with this code (indentation off, parameters not being passed). See the comments:

```
 class Node(object):

    def __init__ (self, code, name, n = None):
        self.data = code
        self.data2 = name # using same variable twice
        self.next_node = n

    def get_next (self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_next (self, n):
        self.next_node = n

    def get_data (self):
        return self.data

    def set_data (self, d):
        self.data = d

class LinkedList (object):

    def __init__(self, r = None):
        self.root = r
        self.size = 0

    def get_size (self):
        return self.size

    def add (self, d, name):
        new_node = Node (d, name, self.root) # you didn't pass name which is a required argument
        self.root = new_node
        self.size += 1

    def find (self, d):
         this_node = self.root
         while this_node:
             if this_node.get_data() == d:
                return this_node # indentation off, don't you want the node, instead of d?
             else:
                this_node = this_node.get_next()
         return None

myList = LinkedList()
myList.add(5, "Trevor")
myList.add(10, "Trevor")
print("size="+str(myList.get_size()))
print(myList.find(10))
```

In the future, please post any error messages you have. It seems that your code had thrown an Indentation error when running it.

Comment: Thanks trans1st0r, but how do i get the function "find" to return me readable data like Code=10, Name=Trevor. All i get is "<__main__.Node object at 0x02DA7CF0>". Thanks again for your help

Comment: just change the return statement in the find function to return the string you want. pretty simple.